# CreateUserWizard not use tables created by aspnet_regsql

Tags: asp.net, sqlmembershipprovider, createuserwizard

How can I configure my CreateUserWizard and Login controls to use the aspnet_regsql tables?

I'm using SQL Membership. I added aspnet_regsql to my project, database and configured in web.config file. When I created a new user, the CreateUserWizard created new tables and did not use the tables created with aspnet_regsql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use new [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx).

New ASP.NET Universal Providers uses Entity Framework, so you do not need to use legacy aspnet_regsql to create tables.

**FYI:** Make sure your connection is positing to the the current database instead of localdb.

Comment: No...  I want use Membership provider... but the tables that I created use aspnet_regsql the Login and CreateUserWizard are creating your own tables  and not used the tables generated with aspnet_regsql.... Any suggestion?

Comment: ASP.NET Universal Providers (included Membership Provider and Role Provider) is a newer version of legacy ASP.Net Membership provider. Please use the new one.

Comment: Thanks... I'll tried to delete some tables and procedures that I don't need use....